# Activiti BPMN doesn't have fonts when I use openjdk

Tags: spring, maven, activiti, java-2d

I'm using activity https://www.activiti.org/userguide/
I update my project to open jdk 8 but it doesn't work. Im getting this error

```
com.sun.faces.context.AjaxExceptionHandlerImpl handlePartialResponseError
java.lang.NullPointerException

at sun.awt.FontConfiguration.getVersion(FontConfiguration.java:n)
    at sun.awt.FontConfiguration.readFontConfigFile(FontConfiguration.java:n)
    at sun.awt.FontConfiguration.init(FontConfiguration.java:n)
    at sun.awt.X11FontManager.createFontConfiguration(X11FontManager.java:n)
    at sun.font.SunFontManager$2.run(SunFontManager.java:n)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.font.SunFontManager.<init>(SunFontManager.java:n)
    at sun.awt.FcFontManager.<init>(FcFontManager.java:n)
    at sun.awt.X11FontManager.<init>(X11FontManager.java:n)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:n)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:n)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:n)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:n)
    at sun.font.FontManagerFactory$1.run(FontManagerFactory.java:n)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.font.FontManagerFactory.getInstance(FontManagerFactory.java:n)
    at sun.font.SunFontManager.getInstance(SunFontManager.java:n)
    at sun.font.FontDesignMetrics.getMetrics(FontDesignMetrics.java:n)
    at sun.java2d.SunGraphics2D.getFontMetrics(SunGraphics2D.java:n)
    at org.activiti.image.impl.DefaultProcessDiagramCanvas.initialize(DefaultProcessDiagramCanvas.java:n)
    at org.activiti.image.impl.DefaultProcessDiagramCanvas.<init>(DefaultProcessDiagramCanvas.java:n)
    at org.activiti.image.impl.DefaultProcessDiagramGenerator.initProcessDiagramCanvas(DefaultProcessDiagramGenerator.java:n)
    at org.activiti.image.impl.DefaultProcessDiagramGenerator.generateProcessDiagram(DefaultProcessDiagramGenerator.java:n)
    at org.activiti.image.impl.DefaultProcessDiagramGenerator.generateImage(DefaultProcessDiagramGenerator.java:n)
    at org.activiti.image.impl.DefaultProcessDiagramGenerator.generateImage(DefaultProcessDiagramGenerator.java:n)
    at com.MyClass.getBpmnDiagram(MyClass.java:n)
```

So, Does anyone know which maven library brings these dependencies of sun and java 2D?
or How I can fix this problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It was fixed installing fontconfig in linux machine.